# Widgets are not loading after moving the wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

Website showing this widget id text instead of widget, yet all the widgets are activated and placed well in admin.
What can be the issue ? I need help in that.

[image]

Comment: Those look like shortcodes.  Did you perhaps deactivate the plugin that allowed you to use widgets in shortcodes?

Comment: @anmari, have the same plugins installed like old site plugins and activated too.

Comment: try like this? <?php echo do_shortcode('[widget id="wp_travel_trip_type-4"]');?> in case if you are using in .php file template file

Comment: Rahul,  Do you know which plugin is creating the shortcode to do that?  It is not native wordpress.  Maybe https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-shortcode/?  DoubleCheck that it is active.